# Future.get() and InterruptedException Asynchronous threading

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, timeout, future

Im using asynchronous threading in my application WITH httpClient. I make a call using the  Future Api like so

```
mStrResults = (String) rssFuture.get();
```

this call attempts to retrieve an html string returned from my Callable httpClient call() method.

What i want to do however is ensure that the get method does not wait too long while executing the call() method. Should i pass a timeout parameter when calling rssFuture.get() or is it ok to just surround with a InterruptedException catch block?

Also is there a default time which the asynchronous thread will wait before throwing an InterruptedException and if so can i set a custom value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a timeout parameter when calling `rssFuture.get()` and catch the TimeoutException. An InterruptedException will only happen if the thread running the your `call` gets interrupted with the `Thread.interrupt` method or if you call the `cancel(true)` method in the Future obj.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Future.[get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), and catch TimeoutException. There is no default timeout for get(), it will wait *forever*.

InterruptedException will not be thrown unless the thread calling Future.get() is interrupted.

Comment: Yeah, well said. After logging both exceptions I arrived at the same conclusion. But I've kept both error handlers.